# How to align divs in a DOM

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to align the divs of the messages but I don't know how.

My intention is about the div's take a style like the next imagen

[image]

in my query I select the user nickname of the emitter and the receiver and in the foreach I take it like this

```
$chat = '';
foreach ($rs as $message) {
print_r($message);

    $chat .= '<div class="single-message'.(($_SESSION["nickname"]==$message->UserEmitter, $usuarioReceptor == $message->UserReceiver)?'right':'left').'">
                <strong>'.$message->UserEmitter.': </strong><br /> <p>'.$message->message.'</p>
                <span>'.date('h:i a', strtotime($message->created_at)).'</span>
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>';

}

echo $chat;
```

but if I do it like that show me an error in the line of

```
(($_SESSION["nickname"]==$message->UserEmitter, $usuarioReceptor == $message->UserReceiver)?'right':'left').'">
```

is my first time make something with JS i hope someone can help me

> Resutl of the Answer

[image]

to make me understand I'm trying to make that cesg dav take a position into the left because is the receiver and cesg av2 take a position at the right because is the Emitter

the source code that I'm using is in [OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmvS5ucAncFGiVG31AMzhS8NzMO9)

> New Foreach

```
foreach ($rs as $message) {

    $chat .= '<div class="single-message'.(($usuarioActual==$message)?'right':(($usuarioReceptor==$message->message)?'left':'')).'">
                <strong>'.$message->UserEmitter.': </strong><br /> <p>'.$message->message.'</p>
                <span>'.date('h:i a', strtotime($message->created_at)).'</span>
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>';

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in this line?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I'm trying to print the nickname of the receiver and the emitter, and it shows but i don't know why they doesnt take the style like the image that i put

Comment: I mean the line that throw an error. `(($_SESSION["nickname"]==$message->UserEmitter, $usuarioReceptor == $message->UserReceiver)?'right':'left').'">`. What is the logic here?

Comment: well I'm trying to say it when the message is from the receiver to put into de left and when is from the emitter put into de right, i know it's  worng but i don't how to make it right

Comment: On your error, you are using comma ( , ) on your conditional and not AND (&&) TRY IT: ($_SESSION["nickname"]==$message->UserEmitter    &&   $usuarioReceptor == $message->UserReceiver)

Comment: @RamonSchmidtRocha I try it but doesn't gime the result that i want

Comment: Your comma doesnt work, so your logic in this conditional is wrong... Try to echo the values of $_SESSION["nickname"]   and  $message->UserEmitter   and $usuarioReceptor and  $message->UserReceive  so you can know what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using flexbox is easy to manipulate elements on screen :) I think it resolves your problem with alignment and with php code at the end of html file for you test on your real code!

```css
.chat {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.message-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message {
 flex-grow: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.message-container.is-emitter {
 align-items: flex-start;
}

.message-container.is-receiver {
 align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <div class="message-container is-emitter">
    <div class="message">EMITTER</div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-container is-receiver">
    <div class="message">RECEIVER</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--

PHP CODE MODIFIED

$chat = '<div class="chat">';
foreach ($rs as $message) {
  $userType = (($_SESSION["nickname"] == $message->UserEmitter && $usuarioReceptor == $message->UserReceiver) ? 'is-emitter' : 'is-receiver'
  
  $chat .= '<div class="message-container ' . $userType . '">
              <div class="message">
                 <strong>'.$message->UserEmitter.': </strong>
                 <br />
                 <p>'.$message->message.'</p>
                 <span>'.date('h:i a', strtotime($message->created_at)).'</span>
              </div>
            </div>';

}
$chat .= '</div>';

echo $chat;

-->
```